# Is there a way to resolve XML namespace conflicts in a returned array of data using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to **XSLT** and i am getting a response **XML** that is displaying in an array with namespace conflicts on the XML elements which I need to make unique to do further work with in another system.

Below is the response XML I am trying to transform using XSLT and also the desired outcome, I want to make each recurring element of `<WorksheetServiceProperty>` unique in a new output XML document following an XSLT transformation using a suffix or prefix on the element.

INITIAL XML DOCUMENT TO BE TRANSFORMED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
         <GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
            <SuccessFlag>true</SuccessFlag>
            <WorksheetServiceProperties>
               <WorksheetServiceProperty>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <WorksheetServiceID>42</WorksheetServiceID>
                  <ServicePropertyID>10</ServicePropertyID>
                  <ServicePropertyName>Job Completed</ServicePropertyName>
                  <ServicePropertyValue>Yes</ServicePropertyValue>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeID>4</ServicePropertyTypeID>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeName>List</ServicePropertyTypeName>
                  <ServicePropertyOrder>30</ServicePropertyOrder>
                  <ForMobile>true</ForMobile>
                  <ForPowerSuite>true</ForPowerSuite>
               </WorksheetServiceProperty>
               <WorksheetServiceProperty>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <WorksheetServiceID>42</WorksheetServiceID>
                  <ServicePropertyID>15</ServicePropertyID>
                  <ServicePropertyName>Crew Comments</ServicePropertyName>
                  <ServicePropertyValue>Collected all items successfully</ServicePropertyValue>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeID>7</ServicePropertyTypeID>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeName>TextBox</ServicePropertyTypeName>
                  <ServicePropertyOrder>5</ServicePropertyOrder>
                  <ForMobile>true</ForMobile>
                  <ForPowerSuite>true</ForPowerSuite>
               </WorksheetServiceProperty>
               <WorksheetServiceProperty>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <WorksheetServiceID>42</WorksheetServiceID>
                  <ServicePropertyID>16</ServicePropertyID>
                  <ServicePropertyName>Items To Be Collected</ServicePropertyName>
                  <ServicePropertyValue>Matress, bed frame, fridge</ServicePropertyValue>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeID>1</ServicePropertyTypeID>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeName>String</ServicePropertyTypeName>
                  <ServicePropertyOrder>2</ServicePropertyOrder>
                  <ForMobile>true</ForMobile>
                  <ForPowerSuite>true</ForPowerSuite>
               </WorksheetServiceProperty>               
            </WorksheetServiceProperties>
         </GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResult>
      </GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

DESIRED OUTCOME

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
         <GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
            <SuccessFlag>true</SuccessFlag>
            <WorksheetServiceProperties>
               <WorksheetServiceProperty1>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <WorksheetServiceID>42</WorksheetServiceID>
                  <ServicePropertyID>10</ServicePropertyID>
                  <ServicePropertyName>Job Completed</ServicePropertyName>
                  <ServicePropertyValue>Yes</ServicePropertyValue>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeID>4</ServicePropertyTypeID>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeName>List</ServicePropertyTypeName>
                  <ServicePropertyOrder>30</ServicePropertyOrder>
                  <ForMobile>true</ForMobile>
                  <ForPowerSuite>true</ForPowerSuite>
               </WorksheetServiceProperty1>
               <WorksheetServiceProperty2>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <WorksheetServiceID>42</WorksheetServiceID>
                  <ServicePropertyID>15</ServicePropertyID>
                  <ServicePropertyName>Crew Comments</ServicePropertyName>
                  <ServicePropertyValue>Collected all items successfully</ServicePropertyValue>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeID>7</ServicePropertyTypeID>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeName>TextBox</ServicePropertyTypeName>
                  <ServicePropertyOrder>5</ServicePropertyOrder>
                  <ForMobile>true</ForMobile>
                  <ForPowerSuite>true</ForPowerSuite>
               </WorksheetServiceProperty2>
               <WorksheetServiceProperty3>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <WorksheetServiceID>42</WorksheetServiceID>
                  <ServicePropertyID>16</ServicePropertyID>
                  <ServicePropertyName>Items To Be Collected</ServicePropertyName>
                  <ServicePropertyValue>Matress, bed frame, fridge</ServicePropertyValue>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeID>1</ServicePropertyTypeID>
                  <ServicePropertyTypeName>String</ServicePropertyTypeName>
                  <ServicePropertyOrder>2</ServicePropertyOrder>
                  <ForMobile>true</ForMobile>
                  <ForPowerSuite>true</ForPowerSuite>
               </WorksheetServiceProperty3>               
            </WorksheetServiceProperties>
         </GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResult>
      </GetWorksheetDetailExtraInfoFieldsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to do this? It's not a good XML format to have.

Comment: I have rolled back your question to what it was when answered. You should post a new question with your new problem. -- P.S. In your new XSLT, you have declared the relevant namespace incorrectly: it needs to be `xmlns:mvm="http://www.mvm.co.uk"`.

Comment: Apologies, new to using these forums. I will try with that name space and if still having problems post a new questions. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no namespace conflicts in the given XML, and what you want to do is easy to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ws="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ws:WorksheetServiceProperty">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{position()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whether it's a smart thing to do is another matter. Siblings with numbered names are difficult to process. A better practice would be to use an *attribute* for the numbering:

```
<xsl:template match="ws:WorksheetServiceProperty">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="number">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: How would the XSLT look if you were to take the attribute approach so I can try both?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.